# Can't load Css in codeigniter

Tags: php, css, html, codeigniter

I am trying to load css in codeigniter 
my css load code is-

```
 <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/home.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and i did in my autoload.php file

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','html');
```

But still not able to load Css.

My folder path is Myproject/application/css

where i am making mistake please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Your css folder should not reside inside the application folder. Put it on the same level as the application folder and your css will load.

Comment: Try putting everything outsite the `application/` folder

Comment: Bring 'CSS' folder at the same level your 'application' folder is present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your Css folder path should be like

```
Myproject/css
```

put it in same level of application folder.